# JQuery merge two functions keyup and focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a form-field I work with two active functions: keyup and focusout.
The functions execute the same code, only the key-up uses a delay-function.

Function for delay:

```
$(function() {
    var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
      clearTimeout (timer);
      timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
  })();
```

Functions for keyup and focusout:

```
    $("#name").on('keyup', function (){
    var textn = $(this).val();
    var nbrCharn = textn.length;
          delay(function(){
                if(nbrCharn > '2'){ $('#nameMsg').html('Nice.'); 
                }else { $('#nameMsg').html(''); }
          }, 1000 );
    });

    $("#name").on('focusout', function (){
    var textn = $(this).val();
    var nbrCharn = textn.length;
          if(nbrCharn > '2'){ $('#nameMsg').html('Nice.'); 
          }else { $('#nameMsg').html(''); }
    });
```

The keyup needs the delay, the focusout does not.
This code works fine, but is it possible to merge those functions, so I don't have the same code twice?

Comment: your delay function looks like it has messed up brackets

Comment: Tnx for the feedback. Tried everything, can't make it work in another way.

Comment: I think actually it is just that you didn't paste the closing brace of the wrapping `$()`

Comment: I assume you do explitly want to only have one timer running with the delay function simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, the timer only runs on keyup, never on focusout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could define a handler that takes an argument which is a completion function

```
var handler = function (completion){
    return function(){
        var textn = $(this).val(),
            nbrCharn = textn.length;
        completion(function(){
                if(nbrCharn > '2'){ 
                     $('#nameMsg').html('Nice.'); 
                } else { 
                     $('#nameMsg').html(''); 
                }
        });
    };
};
```

and then define the handlers

```
$("#name").on('keyup',handler(function(cb){delay(cb,1000);}));
$("#name").on('focusout',handler(function(cb){cb();}));
```

Comment: in this case, the value of $this inside the handler will be wrong. you could either solve this with `.bind()` or with my closure answer

Comment: @Plato the function returns another function which is then used as the event handler so `this` has exactly the same meaning as in OPs code

Answer (score 1):

If you use several events in one handler use the event object argument to check `event.type`

```
$("#name").on('keyup focusout', function (evt){
     if(evt.type === 'keyup'){
        /* keyup only code */
     }
});
```

Or something like

```
 var delay = evt.type === 'keyup' ? 0 :1000;
```

then use delay() for both

Comment: Very helpful already being new to jquery, because it's one function less. Remains the fact that in the delay-function is parent, so the same code is still used twice.

Comment: don't understand what you mean by it still gets used twice

Comment: $("#name").on('keyup focusout', function (evt){
     if(evt.type === 'keyup'){
        /* delayfunction and code for html */
     }
     if(evt.type === 'focusout'){
        /*  same code for html */
     }
});

Comment: no, can set the html once. Set delay 0 for one case, 1000 for the other

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward way is to [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) one event from the other after a delay:

```
$("#name").on('keyup', function (){
   var $this = $(this);
   setTimeout(function() {
       $this.trigger('focusout');
   }, 1000); // milliseconds
});
```

---

Alternatively, [use an external callback function for both](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/06d62v0q/), using [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to pass along the same element as `this`:

```
$("#name").on('keyup', function() {
   var el = this;
   setTimeout(function() { callbackFunc.call(el) }, 1000); // milliseconds
});
$("#name").on('focusout', callbackFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing the relevant jquery `this` object to a function:

```
var delay =
(function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  }
)()

$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
  $("#name").on('keyup', function (){
    var self = this;
    delay(
      (function(self){
        return function(){ 
          writeNameMsg(self)
        };
      })(self)
    , 1000 );
  });

  $("#name").on('focusout', function (){
    writeNameMsg(this);
  });
}

function writeNameMsg(self){
  var textn = $(self).val();
  var nbrCharn = textn.length;
  if(nbrCharn > '2'){
    $('#nameMsg').html('Nice.');
  } else {
    $('#nameMsg').html(''); }
  }
};
```